# How to pass two arguments to a parent component function from child component angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a requirement in which I have to call a parent component function from child. As obvious we can use `@Output` parameter with `EventEmitter` to achieve this. But the challenge here is the parent component is something like this

```
func(param1,param2){
}
```

I want to call this method from the child so I used something like this.

```
@Output() childToParent = new EventEmitter<object>();

callParentMethod(){
this.childToParent.emit({param1:this.param1,param2:this.param2});
}
```

It is able to call the function that I have seen but the parameters are not getting passed.
Can anyone please suggest what am I doing wrong or missing something?

Comment: Please share you code , create a https://stackblitz.com/.

Comment: You can inject the parent component into the child and then call the corresponding method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try like this:

parent.html

```
<child  (childToParent)="func($event.param1, $event.param2)"></child>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-961aei?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**